# Flutter Build Error Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Unexpected input file: //development/${Project name}/ios/Yes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I'm new to development. I'm facing a Swift Compiler Error in my 1st Flutter mobile app project in order to build the app on the simulator.

[See here for the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GRBN.png)

I've spent almost a week checking all the online relevant resources such as the below, this issue still hasn't been solved. I checked everything related to X Code such as my Apple Developer account, Provisioning profile/Certificates, etc, and I don't see any issues there.

■Relevant articles (hasn't solved my issue)

[Xcode 8.2, Swift Compiler Error: error: unexpected input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186033/xcode-8-2-swift-compiler-error-error-unexpected-input-file?newreg=ccf02bafb43e4439833751a32c5196d3)

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/83419

[Why I am getting swift compiler error in Xcode 10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655118/why-i-am-getting-swift-compiler-error-in-xcode-10-1)

See the details below. Any help/comments/questions will be much appreciated :)

■My environment

-Flutter:3.3.2

-X Code:14.0.1

-VS Code:1.72.2

-Mac OS: Montrey 12.5.1 (M1 Air)

Comment: I think Xcode wasn't able to find that directory or file. How did you setup Flutter? Cocoapods?

Comment: You have any file under ios folder with name 'Yes'?.
Looks like your path is not correct. You have to run file with the extension .xcworkspace

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez Thanks a lot for your question:) Not sure how exactly I should reply since I don't have sufficient knowledge. However, yes, I use Cocoapods. I'm not sure if I used it to setup Flutter. I just followed the official Flutter install instruction as below. 
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos

Comment: @FaizanDarwesh Thanks a lot for your comment:) There are no folders/files named 'Yes' under the iOS folder. I'm not sure what to do to fix the path. Could you please show me how to run a file with the extension .xcworkspace?

Comment: @FaizanDarwesh Now I know what you meant. I opened the project file from .xcworkspace. However, I get the same error messages from X Code.